# How to set by default blank kendo ui numeric textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I want to set kendo ui numeric textbox by default blank

```
<script>
    $("#ProductModel_CostFrom").kendoNumericTextBox({
        min: 0,
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ProductModel_CostFrom").kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 0,
        });
    });
</script>
```

but in this by default it takes 0.00 value 
 so please give me solution 
How to set by default blank kendo ui numeric textbox

Comment: Not sure what are you doing but when I run your code (see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2zn7E/) it displays the value as blank, unless you assign an initial value (check difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2zn7E/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
   $("#ProductModel_CostFrom").kendoNumericTextBox({
        min: 0,
        value: " ",
    });
   $(document).ready(function () {

      $("#ProductModel_CostFrom").kendoNumericTextBox({
           min: 0,
           value: " ",
       });
    });

 </script>
```